# Send email button greyed out

Tags: windows-10-mobile, email

Starting this morning, whenever I try to reply to emails on Windows 10 Mobile from my Gmail account, the send email button is greyed out:

[image]

The funny thing is that if I create a new email, then the send button is **not** greyed out. Also, I keep receiving emails without issues as usual, calendars and contacts are working fine etc, so the only issue is I cannot reply to emails.

I haven't found anything online so far (nothing recent at least), does anybody have any idea how to solve this (ideally, without deleting and readding the account).

If it helps, this is a Lumia 640 XL.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem on a Windows 10 Lumia 640. The delete and send keys are greyed out on replies and even weirder the delete key on the onscreen keyboard does nothing! The problem started today. I am able to send new emails, just not replies. Sounds like some kind of auto-update on Outlook Mail for Windows 10 Phone just broke stuff. :(

Comment: The Outlook Mail app did receive an update today, I believe. Can you check what version of the app you're running? Go to Settings -> About.

Comment: @Indrek Version is 17.6868.40732.0. Unrelated, but you could tell this is a Microsoft app only from the version number.

Comment: I have the same version on my Lumia 950, but I'm not seeing the problem you described. Have you tried restarting your phone? You could also try rotating the phone to landscape and back - this fixed an issue for someone on Windows Central forums, although their problem was with the controls being aligned incorrectly, rather than disabled. Still, worth a quick try.

Comment: @Indrek I tried both of your suggestions but unfortunately they didn't work. Actually, if I rotate the screen, the delete button comes back to life, but the send button disappears. I guess I'll just have to wait for an update.

Comment: Sorry I can't offer more help. Be sure to report the problem in the Windows Feedback app, though.

Comment: @Indrek no worries, thanks for the help! I'll report asap

Comment: Can you still tap it? I know it's sometimes greyed out for me, but I can still click it.

Comment: @RareNCool no I can't, it's totally disabled. Also, like another user mentioned, the delete key does not do anything when you write an email anymore.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour on my Lumia 630. Same app version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed and added my google account and it solved the problem.

Solution is taken from [this Windows central forum](http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10-mobile-insider-preview/423972-cant-reply-forward-emails-outlook-send-button-greyed-out-build-242-a.html.).

Comment: Link appears to be dead.

Comment: I see - anyway, removing and adding the account solves the problem.

Comment: I have had the same problem for ages. Removing then adding the account from scratch worked for me too.